# Is it possible to grep for a deleted file on an APFS Filevault enabled SSD?

Tags: mac, ssd, data-recovery, file-recovery, apfs

Due to a bug in github desktop I lost about a month worth of work on a personal project. If I could recover just one python script from it it would save me a ton of time re-doing it.

I've been looking into ways I could try to recover the file by mounting and decrypting the drive and using grep to search for certain strings. While researching this I ran into this statement:

> If the files were deleted from a Macintosh SSD, they are usually
> beyond recovery due to the TRIM command which wipes their content as
> part of the system disk management routine. However, the copy-on-write
> feature of APFS may make the situation a little bit less hopeless.
>
> -https://www.ufsexplorer.com/solutions/recover-deleted-files-macos.php

Is this true? Is it worth trying to recover this file in this manner?

Comment: Seems like you have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here: So when you say “I lost about a month worth of work on a personal project.” Do you still have the `~/.git/` directory in your project? What exactly makes you think you lost stuff?

Comment: I believe I ran into this problem: https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/5874

Git log shows no commit history, but yes there is still a .git directory.

Comment: Wow. That seems past horrible. Unsure what can be done. My true sympathies to you. Hope for the best, I guess?