# Is it possible to recover a file via PyCharm (jetbrains) localhistory binaries?

Tags: data-recovery, file-recovery, pycharm

I [lost a number of files](https://superuser.com/q/1614375/167207) due to a destructive bug in [GitHub Desktop](https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/5874) and I’m trying to figure out what my best chances are for recovering one of them that was especially important.

I have located the PyCharm Local History binaries, but I am unable to access the Local History feature from within the Pycharm Project at all. It's simply greyed out. The files closed automatically in PyCharm when they were deleted.

Is it possible I could recover this file from the binaries I located and how might I accomplish this?

Comment: I don't know what kind of history pycharms stores, but binary files can be opened in a hex editor to let you search for/read any text stored within them. Unless compression/encryption is used.